# Xen image to VirtualBox - Could not read from the boot medium

Tags: virtualbox, xen

I have a problem with moving xen img to virtual box. After executing the below command, I made the newly created vdi file Primary Master of my virtual machine.

> VBoxManage convertdd disk.img vb.vdi

But it kept complaining about the error in the title. Same thing happened with the command below:

> VBoxManage convertfromraw disk.img vb.vdi

How can I solve this issue?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

XEN doesn't use a "real" boot sector, so there is none for you to boot from in VirtualBox.

You need to boot a live linux on your VB and try to fix your bootsector yourself. This hugely depends on your used distribution, but it can be done and should be very straight forward.